# Tengo problemas con las rutas absolutas en Django

Tags: python, django

Al intentar acceder a archivos en subcarpetas de mi media folder usando, por ejemplo, el código

```
>import os
os.path.isfile("D:\\Users\\me\\Djangoproj\\media\\text\\x.txt")
```

obtengo un resultado boolean Falso. Sin embargo, al repetir el mismo comando en una terminal usando directamente python3, obtengo un resultado verdadero.

Estoy usando python 3.8 y django 4.0.3.

Comment: ¿Si importas otros recursos de esa manera, te devuelve bien?

Comment: Supongo que es un error copiando y pegando, pero por si acaso fuese el problema,  la ruta no está bien escrita. Debería ser "D:\Users\me\Djangoproj\media\text\x.txt" Te falta un "\" y las comillas del final.

Comment: @LaCharcaSoftware
Si tiene la diagonal y comillas que mencionas y aun así no encuentra las rutas a los archivos...

Comment: debes escapar los backslash ejemplo: `"D:\\Users\\me\\Djangoproj\\media\\text\\x.txt"`

Comment: @Bryro Si, los backlash están escapados como indicas.

Comment: puedes agregar un screenshot de la ruta en tu computadora....??